# Using enumerations in Domino / Eclipse Web Service Provider

Tags: eclipse, web-services, lotus-domino, lotus, domino-designer-eclipse

Are enumerated values allowed in Eclipse / Domino Designer web service provider?  I set my compiler to 1.6 and it allows me to declare enums, but when I try to incorporate it in the service without messing with the WSDL directly, it gives "The requested operation failed".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to fix "Syntax error, 'for each' statements are only available if source level is 1.5"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34273144/unable-to-fix-syntax-error-for-each-statements-are-only-available-if-source)

Answer (score 0):

There [are advices](http://lekkimworld.com/2007/08/27/discovering_notes_8_enabling_java_5_source_compilation.html) to set `JavaCompilerTarget=1.5` in notes.ini, then restart Notes. But it does not work for me (Notes 8.5.3).

I solve this task using the following steps.

1. Create new webservice provider and declare Java 1.5 specific field inside of webservice class. For instance:

> > private java.util.List<Integer> myList;

[image: declaration]

2. Then click on lightbulb icon at the left and select "Change project compliance and JRE to 1.5"

[image: set project compliance to 1.5]

3. Remove `myList declaration and save the class.

Now you can use Java 1.5 specific declarations such as enums.

[image: voila]

The same approach works elsewhere in Notes, where you want to solve the same task. Not only for WebService providers.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in IBM Designer, it won't save the Java Compiler Version.
You have to set the target version in every agent on it's own.

Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34294200/5330578) for detailed description solve your problem.

**Edit**

To set the compliance level for an agent open the agent and open a java class. Open Menu Project / Properties -> Java Compiler. Set to "Enable Project special settings" and set "Compiler Compliance Level" to 1.6.

Comment: You should flag this question as a duplicate if you feel that it is such.

Comment: @JAL Sorry, I can't flag questions as duplicate, because I don't have 3000 reputation points, but you can.

Comment: You don't need 3000 rep to flag a question as a duplicate.  You should be able to flag at 10 rep.

Comment: @JAL Unfortunately that's not true, I can't even comment on any question, only in reply. [Privileges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges)

Comment: Ah I am mistaken, it looks like 50 rep is required.  Voted to close as a dupe.

Comment: @JAL Ok, I was mistaken, 50 is enough. 3000 is for moderation of duplicates. Have a nice day :)