# Unable to fix "Syntax error, 'for each' statements are only available if source level is 1.5"

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I am writing a Java Agent which uses parameterized collection types and enhanced-for loops. Domino Designer 8.5.3 then tells me to change the project's compliance level to 1.5 in a quick-fix action.

If I do that, the project rebuilds and nothing changes. Nothing happens if I go to the project's Java Compiler settings to set it manually, or change it in the workspace settings either. How can I get rid of this error?

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the offending code, saving, changing the setting, exiting out of everything (designer, notes client, admin client), restarting, opening the code and removing the comment marks?

Comment: Thanks. I had already tried that. I just solved the problem, I'm just not sure what I did. It seems that the 1.6 JVM was not in the build path. After I added it and changed the project's compliance to 1.5 by the quick-fix action and the error is gone. What is strange is that I had tried changing the workspace's compliance and it did not solve it, so I'm not sure what happened.

Answer (score 2):

There is an annoying bug in Domino Designer. The "Compiler Compliance Level" in File / Preferences will always show 1.5 after a client restart and has no affect at all on Java Agents.

To set the compliance level for an agent open the agent and open a java class. Open Menu Project / Properties -> Java Compiler. Set to "Enable Project special settings" and set "Compiler Compliance Level" to 1.6.

[image]

To view the compliance level for a agent open the agent view, click on a agent (don't open it) an look at Properties / Fields, the fields "$JavaCompilerSource" and "$JavaCompilerTarget" will show the information.

[image]